# what is causing this error message [Error]: "Client 'host' unknown - use 'client' command to create it."?

Tags: perforce

Whenver I try to run p4 command `p4 change -o` or pythonically `p4.fetch_change()`

I get this error message !

[Error]: "Client 'hostname' unknown - use 'client' command to create it."

Does anyone know why am I getting this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a client workspace defined.  The changelist spec you get from `p4 change -o` is the spec for the default pending changelist associated with your current client.  If you don't have a client, you'll get that error.  You'll see the same behavior for any other command that depends on a client spec (which is most of them).

As the error says, use `p4 client` to define a new client specification.  If you already have a client for `hostname`, use `p4 set` to set `P4CLIENT` to the name of that client.

Comment: Actually the current client got created when i was experimenting, and it doesn’t exist on disk, but i have come to learn that client is the workspace directory name as well. So I am wondering how to specify existing client name when caling `p4.connect()` or how can I set or change client after I am connected

Comment: The client doesn't need to match the workspace directory name (that's the `Root`, which is its own field in the client spec).  You can't change the client name within a single connection session because it's part of the initial connection settings; you'll need to open a new connection to change the connection settings.